# What's more important with RAM memory: fast timings or higher clockspeeds?

Tags: memory, ddr2

I do a lot of gaming on my machine, and have the option of running

- PC6400 (800mhz) with 4-4-4-12 timings
- OR PC8000 (1000mhz) with 5-5-5-15 timings.

Which memory configuration will benefit intensive gaming more?

FYI, I have a Wolfdale C2D @ 4.5ghz and GTX-280 SLI if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lean toward the one with the higher frequency being faster but generally they will be nearly identical in speed.

for example the

800mhz /12 is 66.66 cycles
1000mhz /15 is 66.66 cycles

800/4 = 200 cycles
1000/5 = 200 cycles

so you can see they should be close to the same speed although in my experience the higher mhz is more flexible with overclocking

Comment: This is incorrect. They won't be the same speed at all. They will have the same latency, but the one with the higher clock speed will transfer data at a higher rate. (For two identical transfers, once the latency time for an operation has passed, the one with the higher clock speed will transfer the data at a faster rate.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're forgetting that the latency timings are in cycles.

```
PC6400 (800mhz) with 4-4-4-12 timings
```

This RAM has an 800MHz effective clock speed (400MHz actual) and a 4 cycle CAS latency. 4 cycles at 400MHz is `10ns`. 12 cycles is `30ns`.

```
OR PC8000 (1000mhz) with 5-5-5-15 timings.
```

This RAM has a 1,000MHZ effective clock speed (500 MHz actual) and a 5 cycle CAS latency. 5 cycles at 500Mhz is `10ns`. 15 cycles is `30ns`.

So they have the same latency and one has a higher clock speed. It's a no brainer, the second one wins.